# Print requested number of entries based off total (reverse ordering)

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a function that will print the number of requested records based off a given total in reverse order (zero-based). If 0 is passed in as the number of requested records, the total is used.

Examples:

1. `total=3`
       `numRequested=3`

   ```
   rec00000002
   rec00000001
   rec00000000
   ```
2. `total=2` `numRequested=1`

   ```
   rec00000001
   ```

While it works for some cases, I have run into an issue when the `numRequested` is less than the `total` and nears 0. Instead of the above results, I get the following:

`total=2` `numRequested=1`

```
rec00000000
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def printExpBuf(total, numRequested):

    # check if we want all entries
    if numRequested == 0:
        numRequested = total

    # skip over entries we don't need
    while (total > numRequested):
        total-=1

    # print results
    while (total > 0):
        print "rec%08d" % (total - 1)
        total-=1
```

I see the problem exists where I am decrementing `total` by 1, but I am at a loss as to how to fix it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For one thing `total--` isn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: Also, `int total` isn't a valid function parameter.

Comment: I can't tell what general behavior you're looking for. If the number of requested records is less than the total number, do you want to start at the highest record or do you want to end at the lowest one?

Comment: @AmyTeegarden I am always looking to start at the highest record.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon is this all of the code? The while loop at the bottom seems to go on forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comment -

> I am always looking to start at the highest record.

This is not what your code is doing, you are first decreasing total , till it becomes equal to the number of requested records. And then printing out the records.

What you actually want to do is to loop and print records till number of requested records become 0 and then return from the function.

Example -

```
def printExpBuf(total, numRequested):

    # check if we want all entries
    if numRequested == 0:
        numRequested = total

    # print results
    while (numRequested > 0 and total > 0):
        print "rec%08d" % (total - 1)
        numRequested -= 1
        total -= 1
```

Comment: What about in the case where there are total of 0 records and 1 was requested?

Comment: Updated the code for that, check both `total` and `numRequested` against `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, this works.

```
def print_exp_buf(total, num_requested):

    # check if we want all entries
    if num_requested == 0:
        num_requested = total

    # skip over entries we don't need
    while (total > num_requested):
        total -= 1

    # print results
    while (total >= 0):
        print "rec%08d" % (total)
        total -= 1
```

The issues you had were:

1. Not decrementing total in the while loop, so the loop would never end.
2. Printing `total - 1` so it would never print the first record.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is just print a reverse order list of the record numbers requested.  That's a much simpler task than all this stuff with decrementing variables; python has a super-simple loop syntax for this sort of situation:

```
def printExpBuf(total, numRequested):
  if (numRequested == 0) or (numRequested > total):
    numRequested = total
  for count in range(numRequested, 0, -1):
    print "rec%08d" % (count)
```

then:

```
printExpBuf(3, 3)
printExpBuf(2, 1)

rec00000003
rec00000002
rec00000001
rec00000001
```